# Create 3D Model for AR App

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, 3d, augmented-reality

I just [downloaded](https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/sdk/ios) the Qualcomm AR SDK for iOS. SO far it has been working well.

Except for one thing, the 3D model the SDK provides is a teapot (which, technically speaking, are just a **.h** file containing all the vertices values of that 3D teapot model, and some corresponding texture pictures).

So here comes my problem, I don't like the teapot. I want to create my own 3D models and display them in my app, instead of that teapot. But I don't know what application can help me create one and export it into a set of **.h** files and texture files so that I could directly import them into my AR project.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) . refer [this blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-3d-models-from-blender-in-opengl.html).

Comment: Btw the blog post really helped!

Answer (score 1):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is the reference free, open source application. You also have commercial alternatives like [3ds Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/) and [Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/). You also have large databases of free models like [this one](http://www.oyonale.com/modeles.php?lang=en&format=OBJ) (most of the free models are .obj but you can get models for loads of others).

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to have a look at `ac3dreader` a little "model" drawing lib that reads AC3D files.

https://github.com/epatel/ac3dreader

I like [AC3D](http://www.inivis.com/) as it lets you work close to the triangles, yet being fairly easy to use and cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Created the model in Blender, exported it to wavefront .obj format. Use [obj2opengl](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/08/27/obj2opengl/) to convert 3D model to .h array file.